# How to refresh gridview of one mdi child form on button click of another mdi child form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview

As i am new to windows Applications i want to know how to refresh an gridview.
I Have an MDI  parent (AdminPanel) and it has two child Form.

1-EditEmp
2-ShowEmp

There is an DataGridview on ShowEmp.cs and when i click on an edit button in the gridview
it opens EditEmp.cs with the values..
When i click on the update button Record in the database is updated and the EditEmp form got closed but datagridview on ShowEmp shows the earlier values..
It is refresed only when i close that form and again opens it..

I want to know how to refersh that gridview when the form EditEmp got closed..without closing the form that contains the gridview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the Grid Once again after EditEmp form close.

```
EditEmp e = new EditEmp();
e.ShowDialog();
BindGrid();
```

So,u have open your EditEmp form using ShowDialog() method.After this you have to bind the Grid once again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh datagridview data on button click.

**EditEmp.cs:** add below 3 line of code on button Click Event

```
ShowEmp obj = (ShowEmp)Application.OpenForms["ShowEmpFormName"];
obj.refreshData(); //ShowEmp Public Function
this.Close();
```

**ShowEmp.cs:** add refreshData function to refresh datagridview

```
public void refreshData(){
//code to Refresh Data or function that you used when load ShowEmp.cs Form
}
```

**Note:** 
 1. Replace ShowEmpFormName with your Unique Form Name like in your case ShowEmp
 2. List item you must use *public* insted of *private* because *private* function you can't accessible outside of class.

for more about modifiers you can visit [MSDN: Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)